# add value to form array on click

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have the below code working onclick.

```
<form action="" name="testform" method="post" id="testform">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="a">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="b">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="c">
<select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="" onclick="document.testform.a.value='12'; document.testform.b.value='111'; document.testform.c.value='123'">1</option>
    <option value="" onclick="document.testform.a.value='21'; document.testform.b.value='222'; document.testform.c.value='232'">2</option>
    <option value="" onclick="document.testform.a.value='32'; document.testform.b.value='333'; document.testform.c.value='233'">3</option>
    <option value="" onclick="document.testform.a.value='43'; document.testform.b.value='444'; document.testform.c.value='344'">4</option>
    <option value="" onclick="document.testform.a.value='54'; document.testform.b.value='555'; document.testform.c.value='345'">5</option>
</select>
```

When you select 1 the hidden fields of a,b,c get the value of 1.

This works fine however I have a larger project in mind here where the user can select multiple values for 'a' throughout the form.  Without onclick I can get this working well eg

```
<input type="hidden" name="a[]" value="1">
```

But when I do

```
<form action="" name="testform" method="post" id="testform">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="a[]">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="b[]">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="c[]">
<select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="" onclick="document.testform.a[].value='12'; document.testform.b[].value='111'; document.testform.c[].value='123'">1</option>
    <option value="" onclick="document.testform.a[].value='21'; document.testform.b[].value='222'; document.testform.c[].value='232'">2</option>
    <option value="" onclick="document.testform.a[].value='32'; document.testform.b[].value='333'; document.testform.c[].value='233'">3</option>
    <option value="" onclick="document.testform.a[].value='43'; document.testform.b[].value='444'; document.testform.c[].value='344'">4</option>
    <option value="" onclick="document.testform.a[].value='54'; document.testform.b[].value='555'; document.testform.c[].value='345'">5</option>
</select>
```

I get nothing inserted into my hidden value.

Why is this?

Is there a better way of doing what I am trying to do with jQuery?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not setting value="" inside the option tag ?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but `onclick="document.testform.a.value = document.testform.b.value = document.testform.c.value = '1'"` is shorter than `onclick="document.testform.a.value='1'; document.testform.b.value='1'; document.testform.c.value='1'"` (but does the same thing). Though it seems to me that having three fields that always have the same value is a bit redundant.

Comment: @sjobe I am not doing this because I haven't seen a way where I can add multiple values at once doing this eg how would it add a different value for a,b,c?

Comment: Yes that can be done jsut tell me which all different values you want for a, b, c???

Comment: Is there any rhyme or reason to the values that the select is assigning the inputs? I am looking for a programmatic way to generate the values. If there's a formula for them, it can be included to save you effort in maintaining this.

Comment: @Vins lets go with if you select 1 a=12, b=111, c=123 like I have updated in the question and I will be able to build from there.

Comment: @DaveL that is a fair comment at the moment I am trying to see if it is possible to get the user to select one field and populate several hidden values so there is no formaula as such at this stage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the modified jsfiddle link for your problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/et3r7/12/ Please check if this helps you. I've made hidden to text in order to display the result you can make it them to hidden.

I had cleaned up your code little bit. Removed all the onClick code.

Comment: Nice answer! Gave an upvote for your effort in seeing it to the end.

Sadly, the comments on the OP now look like different values may be necessary for the inputs?

Comment: @Vins This works better than what I had thanks however my mistake in describing my question the values of a,b,c may be different, I have updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: @ak85 Please check now. whether this meets your requirement. I've updated the fiddle link.

Comment: @Vins this looks great thanks a lot, this was what I was trying to do

Comment: @Vins I notice you changed your fiddle from 11 to 12 to include the if statement. Why was this? I couldn't see anything wrong with 11?

Comment: Yes only to take care of the blank values. when its a data-value is blank we cannot access the array indexes it will throw errors.

Comment: ok thanks @Vins one thing I didn't consider is as it is an array I plan to have the select box appear multiple times on the page eg http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/et3r7/14/ I have tried adding an ID to each select box but this doesn't seem to stop it adding the same values to each instance of the select box. I thought because you had $(this).find what you had might work but it doesn't seem to?

Comment: @Vins thanks for all your help.  This looks to work except on line 3 I had to change 'div' to 'div_'

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that `.value` is a property of an array. (Actually, I'm a derp, it may be a property of an array element - I'll look it up) I would also look at the [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method of an array for adding elements.

There are a couple other ways you could approach this task. With JS, you could abstract this a little, and  make a single function to do the work that each click is doing, which would make your code much more succinct.

This is easily done if jQuery, too, but I would be evaluating whether this bit of functionality is worth the additional download (jQuery is 32KB minified and zipped).